# SQL TOP 5000 faster than normal query with less than 5000 result rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I noticed some strange behaviour:

Running this query:

```
SELECT TOP 5000  t1.f1,t1.f2,t1.f3 
FROM t1
JOIN t2 on t1.f1 = t2.f1
WHERE t2.f1 IS NOT NULL AND (t1.f5 != t2.f3)
```

Results in 3447 rows in 2 seconds.

Running this one:

```
SELECT t1.f1,t1.f2,t1.f3 
FROM t1
JOIN t2 on t1.f1 = t2.f1
WHERE t2.f1 IS NOT NULL AND (t1.f5 != t2.f3)
```

Runs forever until I stop it (at least 120 minutes!!).

Table `t1` and `t2` hold about 500k records.

I always assumed the `TOP` statement did not matter if the total number of rows lay below that number, however, there seems to be a very significant difference. Is this normal (if so, why) or is this just a fluke?

**EDIT:**

As requested:

**t1:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
    [f1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [f2] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [f3] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [f4] [int] NOT NULL,
    [f5] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_t1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [f1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

**f2:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t2](
    [f1] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [f2] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [f3] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [f4] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [f5] [date] NULL,
    [f6] [date] NULL,
    [f7] [nchar](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_t2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [f1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Execution plans:**

With top:
[image: Execution with top]

Without top:
[image: Exec w/o top]

Looking at this I would have to conclude that the `sorting` (WHY is it doing that??) causes the delay... Would you agree?

Edit2: as requested, execution plan with loops option without top:
[image]

Comment: Did you look at the execution plans?

Comment: I just did (thanks did not know that feature). From what I read, I could interpret it as such that the query first takes the first 5000 rows of t1. If that is the case, that would be very undesirable..

Comment: Is this condition `t2.f1 IS NOT NULL` meaningful? will t1.f1 be null at all?

Comment: @saratis . . . No.  `Top` refers to the result set, not the input tables.

Comment: DB experts: correct me if wrong. `TOP` starts streaming the results as soon as it finds any rows with matching criteria. For other scenario, it will find all the matching rows and dump it once it is done fully. Is that right assumption?

Comment: @shahkalpesh . . . Good catch.  That condition is redundant, because NULLs would fail the join test. And, for your second question, no.  The database does not cache results necessarily, although when using an `order by` or `group by` it might need to produce almost the entire result set before returning anything.

Comment: Yeah the `t2.f1` was leftover from a previous version of the query, should not have any influence though. Good to know that `TOP` only looks at the result set. That does however leave us without an explanation.

Comment: @saratis: So, removing `t2.f1 IS NOT NULL` didn't make a difference?

Comment: The "top 5000" are going to be arbitrary if you have no order by, so your assertion that selecting the top from t1 is undesirable doesn't make sense to me.  If you add an "order by" on what is important to you, does that change the two queries performance?

Comment: If you want help, post table and index definitions as well as the execution plans.

Comment: @Brian posted the structure and plans. Would suggest sort is creating an issue here.

Comment: Did you try `option(loop join)`? Does this help?

Comment: Query 1, your where clause is comparing t1.f5. Query 2, your where clause is comparing t1.f3

Comment: Your two `WHERE`s look different to me: one has "t1.f3 != t2.f3" but the other has "t1.f5". If the cardinality of the two columns is different (or they are indexed differently), that will surely influence the query planner.

Comment: Whoops sorry, edited query 1, but not 2, they are in fact the same, exept the TOP part.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović tried that, it does change the execution plan to look a lot more like the TOP 5000 one, but still does not show any results.

Comment: I may be missing a significant detail here, but did you not say t1 and t2 have 500k rows? That's significantly more than 5000. Would this not explain the difference. Obviously it should perform better than what it is, but that's a different question.

Comment: @anothershrubery from what I understand, the top 5000 only affects the result set, not the input set, so that should not matter. I am, however, not the expert.

Comment: Could you please post execution plan with loop option?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Done. This one had been running for 11 minutes when I stopped it.

Comment: Questions: 1) are these the Esitmated plans or the Actual plans? 2) what are the estimated (and actual, if available) row counts from the two Clustered Index Search/Seeks in both versions.  3) (very important) What is the warning sign on the "Select" icons indicating?  Hoover over it with your cursor to see the details.  If it says "Missing Statistics" then that is likely the problem.

Comment: Tables are reversed. It should produce identical plan if you reverse order of tables in from clause. If I'm correct, the reason top produces much faster query is because optimizer sees that it only needs 1% rows (because f1 is unique) and uses nested loop to retrieve first 5000 and probe into t2 expecting that `t1.f5 != t2.f3` be mostly true. In second case it expects to return almost 500K rows, so it optimizes for merge join which requires to sets to be in order. The problem here is that f1 in both tables are of different type and thus sorts differently.

Comment: @RBarryYoung 1) For the query with Top it is the actual plan, for the others, I can't get the actual plan because it never finishes. 2) For f1: 486185, for f2: 487707 3) Warnings are in XML: `<PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Cardinality Estimate" Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[t2].[f1],0)" />
              <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Seek Plan" Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[ES].[iEpisodeId],0)=[t1].[f1]" />`

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović What do you mean 'reversed'? I don't really understand your explanation. Could you maybe formulate that more clearly as a seperate answer, so that we get out of this comment list and can discuss it seperately...

Comment: The order of tables in `from clause`. If you say `from t2 inner join t1 ...` I expect to see exacly the same execution plan. Note: I'm using comments because I'm not exactly sure that my attempt at explanation is viable.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović OMG, another mistake, I hate anonymizing stuff, of course the tables are in the same order, I just drew the labels wrong...

Comment: Oh well. The same plan but different outcome is out of my reach. But if I were in your shoes I would see if I can convert `f1` from `t2` to int and see if this works better. It should.

Comment: @shahkalpesh:  Actually, it depends on which query plan it settles on.  In this case it does do that, but in other cases it may not start returning rows any earlier than a non-TOP query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that your two tables, [t1] and [t2] have completely different (and largely incompatible) data types for the JOIN column, `f1`.

This makes it impossible for the Query Optimizer to generate an accurate estimate of how many rows are going to match between these two 500,000 row tables.  It appears to be using a default "guess" that in this case is a gross *over*-estimate of the actual number (3477).  Because of this, when you are not using the TOP, it thinks that it will be more efficient to Sort and then Merge the rows (O(NLogN)) than to do nested loops (O(N^2)), because it does not realize that the (merge) JOIN will actually eliminate almost all of the rows.

When you have the TOP 5000 on, it realizes that the Nested Loops are better, because it will get cut off at no more than 5000 (far less than 500k^2, and even less than 500k * Log(500k) ).  But unlike  Nested Loops, the Merge-Sort cannot be done incrementally, it has to have all of the rows for the Sort first.  So cutting off the output at 5000, would not save you much at all, thus making Nested Loops clearly the better option (even with the bad JOIN estimate).

---

The root problem here is that the column T2.f1 is an NCHAR(10) which is a really bad choice for something that looks like it is supposed to contain an integer.  The best solution would be to change that column's datatype to INT.

If for some reason you cannot do that, then depending on your version of SQL Server, you may be able to end run this by adding a persisted computed column that calculates an INT converted value of [f1] and then throw a compatible index on *that*.  This would allow both indexing and statistics to work again for queries like this.

As a last resort, you could also use a Query Hint.  I do not normally recommend them as because they tend to be stopgap solutions that cause problems later on.  However, if you felt this was your only choice, then adding `OPTION (FAST 1000)` to the end of you query would probably work.

Comment: Wow, im having trouble understanding your answer :). But some questions. `1)` When using the `loops option` on the non-top query (execution plan three) it also uses nested loops, so why is it still so slow. `2)` Will changing t1.f1 to int make a difference? `3)` t1.f1  and t2.f1 DO have almost 500k matches, it's just the other criteria that don't match (in 3477 cases), did you understand that correctly?  `4)` Is there a way to make this query show results in minutes (w/o TOP)?

Comment: When I look at the TOP query plan and the LOOP JOIN query plan, it is clear that its cardinality (row count) estimates are significantly different.  This should be impossible unless something else significant has changed.  Try extracting the query plans and executing the two queries again, right next to each other.  Those rowcounts (from the Clustered Index Seek/Scans) should match, and if so, then the run-times should match also.  If they do not, then something deeper is off and we'll need to see more of the detail in the query plans.

Comment: I'm sorry, I normally use MySql, can you explain to me what I need to do?

Comment: I'm not sure have the right reason for the difference between the TOP 5000 query and the non TOP query, but you solution definitely works! Changed the the types in T2 to match T1 (had to truncate the table to make that happen) and now the query runs really fast. So thanks!

Answer (score 2):

SQL queries can be optimized in many different ways.  Two common ways are "fastest first row" and "fastest last row".  That is, do you want to minimize the time to get to any result or the time to get the complete result set.

I would guess that these two versions are being optimized differently.  You can check this, as Aaron suggests, by looking at the execution plans.  My usual bet is that the slow version uses nested loop joins.  You can fix this with an optimizer hint, such as:

```
<your query>
option (MERGE JOIN, HASH JOIN)
```

There are other possibilities.  Perhaps these tables are being updated, and the tables happened to have full table locks when you ran the second query.  You can check this using `sp_who2`.

Comment: Thanks, the tables are not being used by anyone else. Aaron's comment led me to believe the query will only look at the first 5000 rows of t1, which is not why I want of course, I want the first 5000 joined rows. I will try your optimizer hint.

Comment: option (MERGE JOIN, HASH JOIN) does not appear to do much.

Comment: That worked out for me! From 5 minutes down to 2 seconds :)